# Electron builder is taking only one builder.js file

Tags: webpack, react-redux, electron

My electron redux app is having 2 entries in webpack as below

```
entry: {child: './src/child', 
        home: './src/app'
       },
output: {
path: __dirname,
filename: '[name].bundle.js',
libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
```

its running fine in local run but when exe is installed in windows.The electron window that uses redux components of home.bundle.js are working fine but other electron window which uses child.bundle.js is not rendering dom components.

but its working fine in local run.

I am using https://github.com/dustintownsend/electron-react-boilerplate